# error with reading data back out of a vector

Tags: c++, loops, vector, count

this is my program for reading data from a text file and storing it into a vector, im having trouble compiling this, any suggesting would be great.
id like to in this example to call all the data for year and month.
im hoping its something simple ive missed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libscat.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Weather
{
  int year;
  int month;
  double tempmax;
  double tempmin;

};

int main()
{
  vector<Weather> data_weather;
  string line;
  std::ifstream myfile ("weatherdata.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline(myfile, line) )
    {   int count = 0;
        if (count > 8) 
        {
            std::istringstream buffer(line);
            int year, mm;
            double tmax, tmin;
            if (buffer >> year >> mm >> tmax >> tmin) 
            {
            Weather objName = {year, mm, tmax, tmin};
            data_weather.push_back(objName);
            count++;
            }
        }

        for (auto it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); it++){ 
        std::cout << it->year << " " << it->month << std::endl;}
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
    cout << "unable to open file";
    }
    scat::pause("\nPress <ENTER> to end the program.");

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Post compiler error. Also `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::getline()` and `std::cout`.

Comment: "I am having trouble" is a vague problem description. What *specifically* are you doing? And what *precisely* is happening when you do it?

Comment: else has an error: expected a statement. It wont compile, i basically want to read some of the selected data ive stored in the vector back out

Comment: C++ has no while/else construct. You're also missing some `std::`s. [Here's the fixed version](http://ideone.com/gr94g9)

Comment: Check your braces. And in the future please include your _complete_ and _unedited_ error messages in the question. It helps a lot in telling what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fixed version with explanation since there still wasn't any real answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libscat.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Weather
{
    int year;
    int month;
    double tempmax;
    double tempmin;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Weather> data_weather;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile("weatherdata.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int count = 0;  // you gotta put it in front of the while loop or you'll
                // create a new variable and initialize it to 0 every time
                // you enter the loop
        while ( getline(myfile, line) )
        {
            // int count = 0; // placed it just before the loop
            if ( count > 8)
            {
                std::istringstream buffer(line);
                int year, mm;
                double tmax, tmin;
                if (buffer >> year >> mm >> tmax >> tmin)
                {
                    Weather objName = {year, mm, tmax, tmin};
                    data_weather.push_back(objName);
                    // count++; // you're still inside the if (count > 8)
                    // you'd probably want to have it outsided the if statement
                    // instead.
                }
            }
            ++count;    //the count from inside. it'll probably do what you wanted
                    //it to do here.

            // you'll probably want to run the for loop AFTER the while loop
            // when the data_weather vector got fully filled
        }
        // the for loop from inside the while now outside
        for (auto it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); ++it)
        {
            std::cout << it->year << " " << it->month << std::endl;
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "unable to open file";
    }
    scat::pause("\nPress <Enter> to end the program.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: im not getting any errors with the code, but when i run it in console all i get is: "Press <ENTER> to end the program." no data is shown.

Comment: sorry all im getting now is "unable to open file", not sure why?

Comment: @jaylad As for you not getting output: The line `if (buffer >> year >> mm >> tmax >> tmin)` expects a line with 2 integers followed by 2 doubles. Have a look if that's right. Also counting from 0 to 8 ignores the first 9 lines and should start outputting the lines 10 and after. You might check if that's the correct number. I don't know what else could be wrong for you to not get output atm.

Comment: @jaylad here's a working version on liveworkspace: [link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3KtgvN$7) note that the 2 lines that got to do with your libscat.h are commented out since they can't be used there and it's using cin for input instead of a file.

Comment: @jaylad For you getting "unable to open file": `std::ifstream myfile("weatherdata.txt");` should require the file to be in the same folder as the executable if you start it normally. If you start it from inside an ide such as Visual Studio the folder might be different. Eg: when starting it from within visual studio your file is expected to be in the project folder whilst the executable is in the project/release folder. An easy way to find the correct folder would be adding: `std::ofstream myfile("testfile.txt");` and checking in what folder that file is created when you run the program.

Comment: yeah ive corrected the file locations and solved that issue, if (buffer >> year >> mm >> tmax >> tmin) is correct ive got that working now, except there is some data missing on the odd month for tmax, this isnt picked up as its not a double?

Comment: Is there a way I can store the blanks as zero into the vector?